# Liferay 6.2 with Tomcat 7 - Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, liferay, out-of-memory, tomcat7

I am using a Liferay and Tomcat bundle: liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp10

Need help with this error during initial startup of the server.

```
Exception in thread "main" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

My Machine: 
OS: Windows 10 64-bit
RAM: 16gb (used 58%)

I have already tried several different values for these tomcat's memory related environment variables located in setenv.bat file:

```
set "JRE_HOME=jdk1.7.0_45\jre"
set "CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% .....  -Xmx8096m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m"
```

Server Log:

```
    Jan 07, 2017 1:38:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11;C:\Softwares\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\Softwares\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.6\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\madhu_000\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\madhu_000\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\madhu_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\madhu_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Softwares\IDE\liferayDevSt-win64-3.0-ga1\DeveloperStudio;;.
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8282"]
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8209"]
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 456 ms
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Softwares\liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp10\tomcat-7.0.42\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/portlet is already defined
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui is already defined
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://struts.apache.org/tags-tiles-el is already defined
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://struts.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui is already defined
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/portlet is already defined
Loading jar:file:/C:/Softwares/liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp10/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:31 AM com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
INFO: Detected server tomcat
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:31 AM com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
INFO: Global shared lib directory /C:/Softwares/liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp10/tomcat-7.0.42/lib/
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:31 AM com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
INFO: Global lib directory /C:/Softwares/liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp10/tomcat-7.0.42/lib/ext/
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:31 AM com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
INFO: Portal lib directory /C:/Softwares/liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp10/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:31 AM com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
INFO: Properties for portal loaded from [file:/C:/Softwares/liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp10/portal-ext.properties, jar:file:/C:/Softwares/liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp10/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal-patched.properties, jar:file:/C:/Softwares/liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp10/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties]
Loading jar:file:/C:/Softwares/liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp10/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
Loading jar:file:/C:/Softwares/liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp10/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal-patched.properties
Loading file:/C:/Softwares/liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp10/portal-ext.properties
Loading jar:file:/C:/Softwares/liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp10/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
Jan 07, 2017 1:38:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
01:38:36,485 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:71] Determine dialect for MySQL 5
01:38:36,515 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:136] Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Exception in thread "main" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your question? For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: I would suggest updating your jvm. It won't help with the OOM but you're quite out of date.

Comment: Did you check, if there is another -Xmx setting somewhere in the command-line? With a tool like Microsoft ProcessExplorer you can check the full command-line at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I really appreciate everyone's replies and their time to help me.

I was able to make Tomcat work.

It worked with these Memory settings and values: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m

Besides, there were several other issues related to MySQL, Port 8080 was taken, etc.

Once again Thanks to Everyone.

Answer (score 0):

please set two option argument : "Xmx" and "Xms"

also this link May be useful :

http://www.henryxi.com/solve-outofmemoryerror-uncaughtexceptionhandler